# Qt Application Crashes After QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, qfiledialog

I have a Qt `(v 6.6.2)` application where I'm trying to open a file dialog and let the user select one or more files. However, my application crashes after the file dialog is closed, regardless of whether files were selected or not. Here's a minimal version of my code:

```
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QStringList>
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>

void LoadFile() {
    QStringList files = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(
                        nullptr,
                        "Select one or more files to open",
                        "/home",
                        "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)");

    if (!files.isEmpty()) {
        for (const auto& file : files) {
            std::cout << "Selected file: " << file.toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "No files were selected." << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "CRASH TEST" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    LoadFile();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The application crashes after the file dialog is closed.
And I never get a console output

I've tried catching exceptions, but none are thrown. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Run your program under a debugger. I'm fairly certain you need an active Qt event loop and application for `QFileDialog` to work, though.

Comment: To be honest I dont understand it the c++ debugger very good at the moment. It does stop at the `qarraydatapointer.h`  at  the line 104: `free(d)`?

Comment: according to [this forum post with the same issue](https://forum.qt.io/topic/151502/my-qt-6-6-0-code-crashs-in-debug-mode-qarraydatapointer-and-not-on-release-on-windows/16) i think QT has different ABI in debug and release modes, so mixing debug and release DLLs will segfault ... are you doing that ? is all code compiled in either debug or release or are you mixing and matching ?

Comment: Hm okay the thing is I use VSCODE not the QT Creator and I use my mingw64 installation where i have copied the includes from qt into. When i run it in the Qt Creator with the QT mingw it works...

Comment: also running the dialog before the main eventloop is actually running is wrong and unpredictable, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38329353/15649230) to run your file dialog in a proper eventloop.

Comment: based on your last comment i think you have a broken C++ ABI at some point, i recommend recompiling QT with the same compiler you intend to use for your application instead of downloading already compiled binaries, the steps to rebuild QT are usually straight forward with cmake.

Comment: Yeah so the problem was my mingw version not being 1120

Comment: Sorry I am pretty unfamilar with c, do you create for every c application its own compiler then inside the application directory?

Comment: @Muddyblackk QTCreator comes with its own mingw compiler shipped with QTCreator, you should be using it to compile apps that will use the compiled binaries you downloaded using the installer, but if you want to use your own compiler to compile your application then you should also recompile QT using the same compiler, this is because C++ doesn't have a stable ABI, a C++ dll compiled using one version of a compiler may not even work with a different version of the same compiler (as you already saw), this is where package managers come in to make life easier such as conan and vcpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what helped me for developping QT-APP in VSCODE-Environment.
The Path to QT is hardcoded, but maybe someone has a more dynamic solution?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/6.6.2/mingw_64")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/bin/c++.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/bin/gcc.exe")


project(MetaDataEditor VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)


set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        test.cpp
)

set(PROJECT_HEADERS
        //add headers
)

set(PROJECT_RESOURCES
        //add .qrc or so
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(MetaDataEditor
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
        ${PROJECT_RESOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET MetaDataEditor APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(MetaDataEditor SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
            ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
            ${PROJECT_RESOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(MetaDataEditor
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
            ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
            ${PROJECT_RESOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_include_directories(MetaDataEditor PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
target_include_directories(MetaDataEditor PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/app/include)


target_link_libraries(MetaDataEditor PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.MetaDataEditor)
endif()
set_target_properties(MetaDataEditor PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE FALSE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS MetaDataEditor
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(MetaDataEditor)
endif()

add_custom_command(TARGET MetaDataEditor POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/bin/windeployqt.exe" "$<TARGET_FILE:MetaDataEditor>"
)
```